# Complex ordering in CakePHP using Containable

Tags: php, cakephp, containable

I`m having a problem with the Containable behaviour.

I would like to know if there is any way to access the contained model attributes for operations like ordering.

For example, I have a model B which belongs to a Model A. I need to order objects of B using an attribute (integer) of A. It would be something like:

```
'contain' => array(
            'A' => array(
                'B' => array(
                    'order' => 'A.integer_attribute'
                )
            )
        )
```

**I know that there are easier ways to do this without Containable, but for reasons which are not worth being detailed here, I need to use it. This is an abstract example, in truth model A belongs to other models and this is just a small part of a deep containable tree.**

I'd be very glad with any help!

**EDIT**

OK, I'll try my best to describe the situation without being unclear:

I have 4 models: **User**, **Category**, **Field** and **UserField**, and their relationships are as follows:

```
Category hasMany User
Category hasMany Field
User hasMany UserField
Field hasMany UserField
```

The opposite of these relations are all belongsTo. The purpose here is that the user belongs to a category, which has many fields that he needs to fill with his information (city, state etc). The information he fills is stored in the UserField table, as each information needs to have its field and the user who provided it.

That said, I need to build a screen which displays, for each category, a list of users and their information. So, I retrieve all the categories and its fields, so I can build a table for each category. Each field has an attribute "no_order", which is the number that indicates the order in which the field appears.

At the same time, I need all of each category's users to display them correctly in the tables. Finally, and there's the problem, I need to have UserField objects ordered by the "no_order" of their respective fields, for each user. So I ended up with something like:

```
$categories = $this->Category->find('all', array(
        'order' => 'Category.name',
        'contain' => array(
            'Field',
            'User' => array(
                'UserField' => array(
                    'order' => 'Field.no_order'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

But this doesn't work, since UserField cannot reach its respective Field's no_order from there.

I apologize if this wasn't clear enough, but for anyone who would spend a little while reading this, I would be VERY grateful for your help!

Comment: You need to share sample data and how you want to have it sorted. What you are describing doesn't make much sense since all **B**'s for any single **A** will be sorted the same.  Perhaps you want to move that `order` to the outer array (i.e., the 'A' => array level)

Comment: Ok, I will edit and try to provide the scenery more specifically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a solution. I don't know how efficient it is, but there it goes:

```
'contain' => array(
            'Field',
            'User' => array(
                'User.privilege = "Solicitante"'
                'UserField' => array(
                    'order' => '(SELECT f.no_order FROM fields AS f WHERE UserField.field_id = f.id LIMIT 1)'
                )
            )
        )
```

Having the raw query solved my problem. Hope it helps anybody who comes across a similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

I am not shure for what do you want so, but I thing that should use joins of cakephp

```
$A = $this->A->find('all', array(
             'joins' => array(
                  array(
                    'table' => 'B',
                    'alias' => 'B',
                    'type' => 'LEFT',
                    'conditions' => array(
                    'B.field_id = A.id'
                    )
                )
            ),
                'conditions' => array(
                'B.field' => 'if_you_want_more_conditions' 
            ),

               'contain' => array(
                   'A' => array(
                      'B' => array(
                         'order' => 'A.integer_attribute'
                        )
                   )
            ),
                'fields' => array('A.field','B.field'),
                'recursive' => -1
            ));
```

Comment: I've just edited my question with a bit more details. I don't think joining would be a good solution for me because this would give me a whole lot of data, since I have in fact 4 tables which tend to have lots of records. Also, I really need the data to be nested, the Cake way. :(